# Python POST request without reloading the page

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a web page using python's requests module.

Here's the scenario:
Once I enter the username password and click submit, the response web page is obtained and the user has to answer security questions.

So,

> POST Request 1 - submit username, password
>
> Response 1 - page containing security questions

This part is quite straight forward.

But for the next step, in order to submit the answers to the security question's, I'll have to make another post request - for which I will have to reload the page again. But once I reload, I end up getting back the initial login page (with username and password fields).

Is there a workaround for it?

EDIT: I am using `requests.Session()` object to carry out all the requests

Here's the code

```
s = requests.Session()

login = {'username': username, 'password': password}
url = 'https://login.xyz.com'
r = s.post(url, data=login)

# r.url is also https://login.xyz.com

answers = {'question1': answer1, 'question2': answer2}
r = s.post(url, data=answers)
```

Comment: Where's your code? Do you the same `Session`?

Comment: The result of your login is most likely a cookie and a redirect url. Try running the entire login action in a browser and capture net traffic on that page (in Firefox or Chrome you can do it in the Development Tools page - F12-). Check each request in the captured traffic and then try to automate accordingly. If I'm correct then the order of operation should be: post the login data, fetch the response, parse the response for the auth cookie, follow the redirect with a new post request that contains the cookie.

Comment: Trying to connect to the target website in your example without disabling certificate checks will result in an error as the website's ssl certificate CNAME is invalid (possibly self-signed, or forged). You might want to validate the response code to 200 or something before you send anything else to the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `requests.Session` to keep the cookies you obtain from the server after you log in.

```
s = requests.Session()
s.post('first url')
s.post('second url')
```

See the docs and examples here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: Yep, I've been using `requests.Session()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well then it's hard to tell you anything specific unless you provide the code

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the login page sent you some sessionId? Usually they are stored in HTTP cookies.

In this case you should send them within the second post request.

Comment: Why -1? I think my answer make sense!

Comment: Most likely, this would be more appropriate as a comment.